# efficient subsetting of data.table with greater-than, less-than using indices

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use `data.table` in R for efficient subsetting using greater-than and less-than like that:

```
library(data.table)

x = runif(10000, min = 1, max = 2)

rowname = seq(10000)
min.x = x - 0.0001
max.x = x + 0.0001

table = data.table(rowname, min.x, max.x)
system.time(x.candidates <- lapply(x, function(x) {table[x > min.x & x < max.x, rowname]}))

#    ->    user  system elapsed 
#       4.87    0.00    4.90 

table2 = data.table(rowname, min.x, max.x)
setindex(table2, min.x)
setindex(table2, max.x)
system.time(x.candidates2 <- lapply(x, function(x) {table2[x > min.x & x < max.x, rowname]}))

#    -> user  system elapsed 
#       4.90    0.00    4.92 

table3 = data.frame(rowname, min.x, max.x)
system.time(x.candidates3 <- lapply(x, function(x) {table3[x > table3$min.x & x < table3$max.x, "rowname"]}))

#    ->    user  system elapsed 
#       1.77    0.00    1.78
```

However, I see not speedup when setting indices and data.frame is even faster. Is it even possible to write this code more efficient in data.table or R in general?

**BEST SOLUTION**

As @eddi pointed out, this is the correct way using .EACHI:

```
table4 = data.table(rowname, min.x, max.x)
system.time(x.candidates4 <- table4[data.table(x), on = .(min.x < x, max.x > x), list(rowname = list(rowname)), by = .EACHI])

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.00    0.01
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use lapply for this? could you not simple use filter() from dplyr? Not sure if that's more efficient

Comment: I'm open to use any package, but I read that data.table is the most efficient.

Comment: data.table might be the most efficient way to store/get data, but your slow-down could be in the actual lapply, which would be unrelated to the data.table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Calling `[.data.table` in a loop, which is what your `lapply` does, is going to be slow because that function has a lot of overhead, and that overhead is not worth it for the tiny operation that you do. The correct way is to do a non-equi join:

```
table[data.table(x), on = .(min.x < x, max.x > x), rowname, by = .EACHI]
#          min.x    max.x rowname
#    1: 1.084668 1.084668       1
#    2: 1.293461 1.293461    7734
#    3: 1.293461 1.293461     739
#    4: 1.293461 1.293461       2
#    5: 1.293461 1.293461    3757
#   ---                          
#30216: 1.324366 1.324366    9999
#30217: 1.324366 1.324366    9635
#30218: 1.869469 1.869469    8740
#30219: 1.869469 1.869469    3302
#30220: 1.869469 1.869469   10000
```

The above is instantaneous. Current column naming is a bit unfortunate (there is an FR to fix that) - imagining first two columns being named `x` should add more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do a *non-equi **self** join*:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 10
set.seed(777)
x <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 2)
rowname <- seq(n)
min.x <- x - 0.0001
max.x <- x + 0.0001

DT <- data.table(rowname, x, min.x, max.x)
DT[DT, on = .(min.x < x, max.x > x), .(i.rowname, x.rowname), by = .EACHI][]
```

> ```
>        min.x    max.x i.rowname x.rowname
>  1: 1.687857 1.687857         1         1
>  2: 1.492193 1.492193         2         2
>  3: 1.345116 1.345116         3         7
>  4: 1.345116 1.345116         3         3
>  5: 1.995050 1.995050         4         4
>  6: 1.695267 1.695267         5         5
>  7: 1.010700 1.010700         6         6
>  8: 1.345016 1.345016         7         7
>  9: 1.345016 1.345016         7         3
> 10: 1.172049 1.172049         8         8
> 11: 1.949361 1.949361         9         9
> 12: 1.249193 1.249193        10        10
> ```

However, [eddi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766724/3817004) is slightly faster.

#### Benchmark

```
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  n = 10^c(2:4),
  {
    set.seed(123)
    x <- runif(n, min = 1, max = 2)
    rowname <- seq(n)
    min.x <- x - 0.0001
    max.x <- x + 0.0001
    table <- data.table(rowname, min.x, max.x)
    table2 <- data.table(rowname, min.x, max.x)
    setindex(table2, min.x)
    setindex(table2, max.x)
    table3 <- data.frame(rowname, min.x, max.x)
    DT <- data.table(rowname, x, min.x, max.x)
    mark(
      Benni1 = lapply(x, function(x) {table[x > min.x & x < max.x, rowname]}),
      Benni2 = lapply(x, function(x) {table2[x > min.x & x < max.x, rowname]}),
      Benni3 = lapply(x, function(x) {table3[x > table3$min.x & x < table3$max.x, "rowname"]}),
      Eddi = table[data.table(x), on = .(min.x < x, max.x > x), rowname, by = .EACHI],
      Uwe = DT[DT, on = .(min.x < x, max.x > x), .(i.rowname, x.rowname), by = .EACHI],
      check = FALSE
    )
  }
)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Please, note the logarithmic time scale.

#### Memory consumption

There is also a huge difference in memory consumption:

```
setDT(bm)[n == max(n), 1:11]
```

> ```
>    expression     n     min    mean  median     max    itr/sec mem_alloc n_gc n_itr total_time
> 1:     Benni1 10000   6.78s   6.78s   6.78s   6.78s  0.1475977     1.5GB   48     1      6.78s
> 2:     Benni2 10000    6.8s    6.8s    6.8s    6.8s  0.1470747     1.5GB   48     1       6.8s
> 3:     Benni3 10000    1.8s    1.8s    1.8s    1.8s  0.5563497    1.49GB   32     1       1.8s
> 4:       Eddi 10000 12.91ms 13.94ms 13.71ms 17.96ms 71.7622591    1.01MB    1    36   501.66ms
> 5:        Uwe 10000 17.21ms 18.42ms 18.11ms 22.54ms 54.2845397    1.04MB    1    28    515.8ms
> ```

[Benni's approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53763673/3817004) allocate 1500 times more memory than Eddi's or mine.