# Subsetting a data.table in a for loop is slower and resource hungry

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, subset, cpu-usage

Working with the `data.table` R package, I noticed really high processor usage when running a simple `for` loop that would subset a dataset using values from another `data.table`. When i say high usage I mean 100% an all available threads for the entire time the loop is running.

The interesting part is that using a `data.frame` object for the same process takes 10x less time for the same output. And with only one of the cores at 100%.

Here is my hopefully reproducible example:

```
chr = c(rep(1, 1000), rep(2, 1000), rep(3, 1000), rep(3,1000))
start = rep(seq(from =1, to = 100000, by=100), 4)
end = start + 100

df1 <- data.frame(chr=chr, start=start, end=end)
df2 <- rbind(df1,df1,df1,df1,df1)
dt1 <- data.table::data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(df2)

test1 <- list()
test2 <- list()

#loop subsetting a data.frame
system.time(
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  no.dim <- dim(df1[df1$chr == df2[i, 'chr'] & df1$start >= df2[i, 'start'] & df1$end <= df2[i, 'end'], ])[1]
  test1[i] <- no.dim
})

# loop subsetting a data.table using data.table syntax
system.time(
for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
  no.dim <- dim(dt1[chr == dt2[i, chr] & start >= dt2[i, start] & end <= dt2[i, end], ])[1]
  test2[i] <- no.dim
})

# is the output the same
identical(test1, test2)
```

And this is the output:

```
> #loop subsetting a data.frame
> system.time(
+ for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
+   no.dim <- dim(df1[df1$chr == df2[i, 'chr'] & df1$start >= df2[i, 'start'] & df1$end <= df2[i, 'end'], ])[1]
+   test1[i] <- no.dim
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  2.607   0.004   2.612 
> 
> # loop subsetting a data.table using data.table syntax
> system.time(
+ for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
+   no.dim <- dim(dt1[chr == dt2[i, chr] & start >= dt2[i, start] & end <= dt2[i, end], ])[1]
+   test2[i] <- no.dim
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
192.632   0.152  24.398 
> 
> # is the output the same
> identical(test1, test2)
[1] TRUE
```

Now, I know there is probably multiple better and more efficient ways to perform the same task, and that I am probably not doing it the `data.table` way. But lets say for some reason you had a script using 'data.frame' objects and you wanted to quickly rewrite the thing to use `data.table` instead. The approach taken above seems perfectly plausible.

Can anyone reproduce the same situation regarding the slowdown and high processor usage? Is it somehow fixable by keeping more or less the same subsetting process or does it have to be rewritten completely to be used efficiently on `data.table`'s?

PS: just tested it on a Windows machine and the thread usage was normal (one thread running at 100%), but still slower. Tested it on a system similar to mine gave the same results as above.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.8.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C           LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C        
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=et_EE.UTF-8 LC_NAME=C           
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1   assertthat_0.2.0 cli_1.0.1        tools_3.5.1      pillar_1.3.1    
 [6] rstudioapi_0.9.0 tibble_2.0.0     crayon_1.3.4     utf8_1.1.4       fansi_0.4.0     
[11] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.1
```

EDIT:

Thanks to everybody for their comments. It appears the slowdown issue is related to the overhead of `[.data.table` as detailed by @Hugh. The same issue was mentioned here [efficient subsetting of data.table with greater-than, less-than using indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763673/efficient-subsetting-of-data-table-with-greater-than-less-than-using-indices) as pointed out by @denis.

The fix proposed by @Frank, while it really is efficient and produces similar output, changes the behavior of the process by removing the loop completely and adds a possibly unwanted column to the original dataset.

EDIT.1:

After my first edit @Frank added another approach which consists of computing a list column using data.table syntax. While its pretty neat, I must admit that I needed a while to figure out what is going on. I figured its just computing lm() on the start and end column of the subset data.table, so I tried reproducing the results using a for loop and data.frames. Timings:

```
> system.time({res <- dt1[dt2, on=.(chr, start >= start, end <= end), .(n = .N, my_lm = list(lm(x.start ~ x.end))), by=.EACHI][, .(n, my_lm)]; res <- as.list(res$my_lm)})
   user  system elapsed 
 11.538   0.003  11.336 
> 
> test_new <- list()
> system.time(
+   for (i in 1:20000) {
+     df_new <- df1[df1$chr == df2$chr[i] & df1$start >= df2$start[i] & df1$end <= df2$end[i],]
+     test_new[[i]] <- lm(df_new$start ~ df_new$end)
+   })
   user  system elapsed 
 12.377   0.048  12.425 
>
```

As long as you have a bottleneck function as lm() you are better off (for control and readability sake) with a basic for loop, but using data.frames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [efficient subsetting of data.table with greater-than, less-than using indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763673/efficient-subsetting-of-data-table-with-greater-than-less-than-using-indices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the user time and the elapsed time is a clue that there's some parallelization going on under the hood:

```r
library(data.table)
chr = c(rep(1, 1000), rep(2, 1000), rep(3, 1000), rep(3,1000))
start = rep(seq(from =1, to = 100000, by=100), 4)
end = start + 100

df1 <- data.frame(chr=chr, start=start, end=end)
df2 <- rbind(df1,df1,df1,df1,df1)
dt1 <- data.table::data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(df2)

print(dim(dt1))
#> [1] 4000    3
print(dim(dt2))
#> [1] 20000     3


test1 <- list()
test2 <- list()

bench::system_time({
  for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    no.dim <- dim(df1[df1$chr == df2[i, 'chr'] &
                        df1$start >= df2[i, 'start'] &
                        df1$end <= df2[i, 'end'], ])[1]
    test1[i] <- no.dim
  }
})
#> process    real 
#>  3.547s  3.549s

print(getDTthreads())
#> [1] 12

bench::system_time({
  for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
    no.dim <- dim(dt1[chr == dt2[i, chr] & start >= dt2[i, start] & end <= dt2[i, end], ])[1]
    test2[i] <- no.dim
  }
})
#> process    real 
#> 83.984s 52.266s

setDTthreads(1L)
bench::system_time({
  for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
    no.dim <- dim(dt1[chr == dt2[i, chr] & start >= dt2[i, start] & end <= dt2[i, end], ])[1]
    test2[i] <- no.dim
  }
})
#> process    real 
#> 30.922s 30.920s
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

But just as big is that you are calling the `[` 20,000 times. Consider this minimal use to demonstrate that the overhead of `[.data.table` for single-row tables dominates the run-time:

```r
library(data.table)
chr = c(rep(1, 1000), rep(2, 1000), rep(3, 1000), rep(3,1000))
start = rep(seq(from =1, to = 100000, by=100), 4)
end = start + 100

df1 <- data.frame(chr=chr, start=start, end=end)
df2 <- rbind(df1,df1,df1,df1,df1)
dt1 <- data.table::data.table(df1)
dt2 <- data.table::data.table(df2)

bench::system_time({
  o <- integer(nrow(df2))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    o[i] <- df2[i, ][[2]]
  }
})
#>   process      real 
#> 875.000ms 879.398ms

bench::system_time({
  o <- integer(nrow(dt2))
  for (i in 1:nrow(dt2)) {
    o[i] <- dt2[i, ][[2]]
  }
})
#> process    real 
#> 26.219s 13.525s
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the insight. And since I am calling `[.data.table` 4 times per iteration looks more than plausible that this would be the reason for the slow down. I figured that there is probably some kind of parallelization going on as well, though what is gained by it is probably lost in the `[` overhead.

Answer (score 8):

> Can anyone reproduce the same situation regarding the slowdown and high processor usage? Is it somehow fixable by keeping more or less the same subsetting process or does it have to be rewritten completely to be used efficiently on data.table's?

I get timings of 5 sec and 44 sec for the OP's two approaches (DF and DT, resp.), but...

```
system.time(
  dt2[, v := dt1[.SD, on=.(chr, start >= start, end <= end), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.01    0.03 
identical(dt2$v, unlist(test1))
# TRUE
```

> But lets say for some reason you had a script using 'data.frame' objects and you wanted to quickly rewrite the thing to use data.table instead. The approach taken above seems perfectly plausible.

This is pretty quick to write once you're used to data.table syntax.

---

If you don't want to modify `dt2` just take the vector directly...

```
res <- dt1[dt2, on=.(chr, start >= start, end <= end), .N, by=.EACHI]$N
```

For this example, a vector of row counts makes sense, but if you have a more complicated output that needs to be in a `list`, you can use a `list` column...

```
res <- dt1[dt2, on=.(chr, start >= start, end <= end), .(
  n = .N, 
  my_lm = list(lm(x.start ~ x.end))
), by=.EACHI][, .(n, my_lm)]

       n my_lm
    1: 1  <lm>
    2: 1  <lm>
    3: 1  <lm>
    4: 1  <lm>
    5: 1  <lm>
   ---        
19996: 2  <lm>
19997: 2  <lm>
19998: 2  <lm>
19999: 2  <lm>
20000: 2  <lm>
```

Comment: I tried the two OP's approach and I don't get the same timing. I do get a longer one for `data.table`. Any idea why ?

Comment: @denis Maybe the data.table one takes longer because `[` has more overhead for data.tables and is used four times per loop iteration..? I still wouldn't expect that to lead to such a large difference as this, though.

Comment: Yes, it is weird to me too... I get 25.19s compared to 3.72s, which is enormous. I love your answer by the way. Never understood the use of `EACHI` before your answer. I learned a lot, thanks

Comment: @Frank Nice answer! I get similar timings for OP's approach. I also think that `[`is causing the timings to go up, though i do not know why...

Comment: Great answer indeed! I was sure that there is a more `data.table` way. Do you think the speed up is due to the reduced `[` calls per iteration alone, or is there something else going on. Also it looks like you get different outputs at the end which in a broader scenario could cause problems downstream. Is there an as efficient way to get the same output directly?

Comment: @MarChers Thanks to Hugh's illustration, I think it is indeed just due to the overhead of `[.data.table` versus `[.data.frame`. My output, a vector of integers, is more natural than yours, a list of integers, I think, and I'd recommend using it unless you have a strong reason not to...? If you want the list instead, `as.list(dt2$v)` should be pretty fast, I think.

Comment: @Frank I completely agree with your point, although what is more natural really depends on the use case. In this case its the row dimension of subsets and it makes sense as a vector. But it could be a summary object on the subset, which makes sense to store as a list. Additionally, lets say the data frames should not be changed in dimensions for whatever reason. Not even considering the removal of a column after computation. Your approach, while faster, would not be applicable anymore since changes the whole process drastically and looses any additional control over the loop.

Comment: @MarChers Ok, I've edited in a couple alternatives (for not adding a column to either table, storing lists). If you need control over the loop -- ie, if it is an iterative computation -- things get messier, but I believe it's still doable in a join.

Comment: @Frank I tested your example that returns a list column and I got timings of ~10 seconds. Which is almost comparable to the for loop using data.frames with an added lm() step. I guess data.table is really efficient in specific tasks but particularly high overhead of some functions might slow it down in special cases.